# Twig iterating though a non nested array ( mysql_fetch_array )

Tags: arrays, loops, twig

When I use the following code:

```
$members = array();
$members[] = array([id]=>"1", [name]=>"name") ; // mysql_fetch_array($row)
```

I can iterate with twig like this:

```
{% for member in members %}
<tr><td>{member.id}</td><td>{member.name}</td></tr>
{% endfor}
```

But I have more rows, and I don't want to allocate the entire array in the memory, it seems like a waste of resources to me.

So how do I loop through:

```
$members =  array([id]=>"1", [name]=>"name");
```

Currently it seems to iterate each array key, in stead of the entire array:

```
{% for member in members %}
<tr><td>{member.id}</td><td>{member.name}</td></tr>
{% endfor}

outputs :
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td></tr>
```

And I don't want to use: (unless there is no alternative)

```
return array( mysql_fetch_array($data) );
```

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? Is moving to PDO an option (instead of the officially deprecated mysql_* functions)?

Comment: PHP 5.3.3. In what way can PDO provide a sollution?

Comment: @Maerlyn this question is about twig. If you dont know the answer, please don't reply. Using PDO will still require me to use  return array( $data->fetch() );

Comment: PDOStatement is iterable, so you need not do a fetchAll, you can pass the statement and {% for %} loop it in your template.

Comment: @Maerlyn, 1) This is not a question about mysql but about iteration through an array . 2) You are not understanding the question at all 3) mysql returns result as an array no matter if you use mysql/mysqli/PDO. 4) Show me a working example how to iterate through a simple array like $row = Array('id'=>1, 'data'=>'test') like in the example in my post. 5) Don't go give me a |cast_to_array extension suggestion, i am asking about native twig. 6) You have single handedly ruined my post, who is gooing to answer this question, with this ridiculous discussion beneath it?

Answer (score 1):

#### Your problem, as I understand it

You wish to iterate through a mysql resultset in twig, without loading the whole thing into php arrays.

#### What you have tried

Loading the first row into a nested array. This worked, but of course you only got the first record echoed in twig.

You're looking for a way to fetch the next row from twig, using only the array. This is not possible, because the array that you have has no connection to the mysql result pointer (besides having the data of the first record).

#### Possible solutions

Note that I have not tested any of the code examples.

1. **Load the whole thing into php**
   If the resultset is reasonably small, like say below a 100 rows, you can just bite the bullet and load it completely into a nested array and pass that to twig. You'll have no problems iterating over it with a simple `{% for %}` loop like in your question.
2. **Create a generator**<sup>[[docs]](http://php.net/generator)</sup>
   This would require that you upgrade to at least php 5.5, which introduced this feature. Your code would look something like this:

   ```
   return array( //I'm assuming this returns data to be passed to twig
       "data"  =>  function () use ($result) {
           //$result is the returned value of mysql_query
           yield mysql_fetch_row($result);
       },
   );
   ```

   You can then do `{% for row in data %}` in your template.
3. **Create an Iterator**
   On older versions, such as your 5.3.3, generators are not available. But that's only a shortcut to writing classes implementing the `\Iterator`<sup>[[docs]](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php)</sup> interface. This involves some code, but you can create a generic class that you can construct using only a result pointer, and you can either `foreach` (in php) or `for` (in twig) over it, just like arrays or generators.
4. **Switch to PDO**
   Depending on your project size this may be the best option (this is the one I recommend). It is very easy to start using PDO, and when you do a query it returns a `\PDOStatement` object, which implements `\Traversable`, meaning you can `foreach` or `{% for %}` over it - without writing any wrapper code. This was one of the main reasons why I switched to PDO from mysql_* (the other being prepared statements).
5. **Create a twig extension**
   Just to mention this one. Probably the most involving (both time and code) solution is to create a `while` tag in twig, and the possibility to call `mysql_fetch_*` on a result pointer.